# Is it possible to improve training error by removing features in a GBT?

Tags: feature-selection, pre-training

The case for test data is clearly explained in many places, but I'm just thinking about training error here. I believe it's impossible in a decision tree, and possible (though unlikely) in a random forest, but have no clue about how to think for a Gradient Boosted Tree. Appropriate noise might be selected for a split, but is it optimized when we consider the entire chain of trees?

Answer (score 1):

"I believe it's impossible in a decision tree".
Unfortunately,  your belief here is incorrect. 
It is possible for a decision tree to improve by 
removing attributes, even when you are testing on
the training data. Let me start with an example, 
and then talk a little about why this can happen.

**Example: Glass Data**

This data set is available in R in the `mlbench` package
or it can be downloaded from the 
[UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Glass%20Identification)
The data consists of measurements on 214 samples of glass. 
Each sample is described by 9 numeric attributes and one 
class variable (the type of glass).

I will use R and the `rpart` package to build decision trees. 
With other algorithms, you might get different results.

```
library(mlbench)        ## For Glass data
library(rpart)          ## Decision trees
library(rpart.plot)     ## Nice plots
data(Glass)

## First build and test a tree using all attributes
GlassTree_All = rpart(Type ~ . , data=Glass)
Pred_All = predict(GlassTree_All, newdata=Glass, type="class")
sum(diag(table(Pred_All, Glass$Type)))
[1] 168

## Now leave out attribute 9, Fe (iron)
GlassTree_Fe = rpart(Type ~ . , data=Glass[,-9])
Pred_Fe = predict(GlassTree_Fe, newdata=Glass[,-9], type="class")
sum(diag(table(Pred_Fe, Glass$Type)))
[1] 170
```

What this shows is that testing the trees on the training data,
**using all attributes 168 instances are correctly classified, 
while using the tree built without the Fe attribute, 170
instances are correctly classified.**

Looking at the two trees

[image: Decision Trees]

you can see that they are mostly the same, but towards the bottom
of the All_Attributes tree, Fe is used. Of course, the tree without
Fe is different from there down.

`<Bloviation on>`

One thinks that at each branch, the algorithm is picking the 
"best" attribute to split on and so making any changes would 
produce a poorer performing tree. But if that were really true,
all decision tree algorithms would produce the same trees - and
they don't. What really happens is that the algorithms use a test
statistic (Information Gain, Gini) to try to pick a good attribute
to split on, but there is no guarantee that it really is the best 
choice. The choice of the attribute determines how the remaining 
instances are partitioned and affects everything in the tree below
the node. It is quite possible for the heuristic criteria used to 
choose the splitting attribute could make a bad choice that make 
lower parts of the tree difficult to separate into distinct classes. 
That happened here. Using Fe to split left no really good way to 
divide the remaining nodes. By removing Fe from the list of attributes,
the algorithm made a different choice and the rest of the tree was better divided. 
This is especially likely near the bottom of the tree where there are
fewer instances being distinguished at each node.

Of course, if this phenomenon is possible for a single decision tree, 
you have to expect that a similar situation could happen with 
other methods that depend on decision trees, like random forests.

`<Bloviation off>`